# Combine related ADTs in a type safe way

Tags: scala, type-safety, algebraic-data-types

I'm designing a typesafe api to work with a "types" -- an abstraction in the application I'm working on. Here is how it looks like:

```
sealed trait EnumType

case object A extends EnumType
case object B extends EnumType
case object C extends EnumType

sealed abstract class TypeInfo[T <: EnumType](val enumType: T)

case class Ainfo() extends TypeInfo(A)
case class Binfo() extends TypeInfo(B)
case class Cinfo() extends TypeInfo(C)

sealed trait TypeMeta[T <: EnumType]

case class Ameta() extends TypeMeta[A.type]
case class Bmeta() extends TypeMeta[B.type]
case class Cmeta() extends TypeMeta[C.type]

case class TypeDescription[T <: EnumType](info: TypeInfo[T], meta: TypeMeta[T])
```

I'm confused about defining a function which would accept a `List` of `TypeInfo` and return `TypeDescription`. I currently implemeted it as follows:

```
//Type parameter with omitted bound? Is that type safe?
def toDescription(lst: List[TypeInfo[_]]): List[TypeDescription[_]] = {
  lst map {
    case a: Ainfo => TypeDescription(a, Ameta())
    case b: Binfo => TypeDescription(b, Bmeta())
    case c: Cinfo => TypeDescription(c, Cmeta())
  }
}
```

To workaround the issue I used `[_]` pattern which does not look typesafely. Is there a way to redeclare the function?

Comment: You can use a **TypeMember** or just remove the generic type altogether. It depends on how do you want to use those classes, but it seems you do not need the generic if you have a list of different ones.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The primary intention of introducing generic type was to disallow `TypeDescription` with, for example `Ainfo()` and `Cmeta()` (without generic it was perfectly possible).

Comment: Right, does it make sense to have a type info without a type meta? Does it make sense to have a type meta without a type info? What other operations are defined on those adts?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `TypeInfo` and `TypeMeta` are two separate concepts with a standalone meaning. It is perfectly sensible they exist on their on. The `List[TypeDescription[_]]` is intended to be send to front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Its type safe , however the 2 type parameters are bound individually to their own constraints and not to one another.
If you are looking to do that , I think you would need to define a method type parameter like so

```
  //Type parameter with omitted bound? Is that type safe?
def toDescription[T<:EnumType](lst: List[TypeInfo[T]]): List[TypeDescription[T]] = {
  lst map {
    case a: Ainfo => TypeDescription(a, Ameta())
    case b: Binfo => TypeDescription(b, Bmeta())
    case c: Cinfo => TypeDescription(c, Cmeta())
  }
}
```

Now if you tried to write

```
case a: Ainfo => TypeDescription(a, Bmeta())
```

you will get a compilation error

Comment: The problem with this is that you can only pass a **List** of the same type of info, which is probably pretty useless for OP.